# mysql select odd number values in a column that includes delimiter separated values

Tags: mysql, csv

My next database table will be set up more optimally.  Unfortunately this one was already set up where one column [data] contains checkbox array values that were saved the following way:

```
value 1|~|value 1 value 2|~|value 2 value 3|~|value 3
```

Not optimal, I know.
What I need is a mysql query that select only the values in [data] column in front of the |~|.  Basically think I need to select the only odd values.

Any help pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated. I tried an if statement in a query and it did not work.  Of course I deleted that by mistake.

Comment: Get the value in query and split it using the |~| in php so you can get the results in php

Comment: it's possible to do it without PHP @balakrishnan

Comment: It is really painful to see data in this format. This is next-level of denormalization. Will be curious to see answers (jugglary) ;-)

Comment: I am hoping to do it in a query because I need to customize the column labels for  when I export the data to csv.  Can you customize the labels in php?

Comment: "Will be curious to see answers" check it out @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: I'm learning a language. Unfortunately, the dictionary I purchased was missing the first few letters, so please help me make sentences using only words starting with D-Z?

Answer (score 1):

> What I need is a mysql query that select only the
>   values in [data] column in front of the |~|.

One thing to note the numbers before `|~|` must be unique. 
It will not show the same number twice.

**Query**

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT 
   SUBSTRING (
       record_data.column
     , LOCATE('|~|', record_data.`column` , number_generator.number) - 1
     , 1
   ) AS number
FROM (
  SELECT 
   @row := @row + 1 AS number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) record_1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) record_2    
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) record_4
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) record_5     
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @row := 0 
  ) AS init_user_params
) AS number_generator

CROSS JOIN (


SELECT 
 *
FROM (
  SELECT 'value 1|~|value 1 value 2|~|value 2 value 3|~|value 3' AS `column`
) AS record 

) AS record_data

WHERE
   LOCATE('|~|', record_data.`column` , number_generator.number) <> 0
```

**Result**

```
| number |
| ------ |
| 1      |
| 2      |
| 3      |
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qrWX1EadZzbHVUGLzwUkPv/0)

Comment: This number generator is really handy. Gotta keep this in mind :) +1

Comment: Thank you so much Raymond Nijland!

Comment: Unfortunately I was not clear with my issue.  Instead of needing only the numbers, what I meant to write was that I need the whole value in front of the |~|.  So what I really need from the 'value 1|~|value 1' is the 'value 1'

Comment: @user1469 so from `value 1|~|value 1 value 2|~|value 2 value 3|~|value 3` you expect the records `value1`, `value 1 value 2`, `value 2 value 3`  right?

Comment: I think that is my problem.  I only want value 1, value 2, value 3.  I am not sure this is possible without php  it has to be, right?  I am stretching, aren't i?

Comment: "I think that is my problem. I only want value 1, value 2, value 3. I am not sure this is possible without php it has to be, right? I am stretching, aren't i? " Well if it's always `"string number|~|"` format your are trying to fetch @user1469 this  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qrWX1EadZzbHVUGLzwUkPv/1 can help