# How to make a MYSQL query to retrieve records without crossing dates?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, range

It is necessary to find in the database all records whose date intervals do not intersect with the requested interval.
Suppose the requested interval consists of start_date and end_date. The data about the intervals of the records is in column date_ranges. The problem is that the data on date intervals have an inconvenient form they are stored in this form:
"YYYY-MM - DD-YYYY-MM-DD/YYYY-MM - DD-YYYY-MM-DD/YYYY-MM - DD-YYYY-MM-DD". How do I create a query to retrieve records without crossing dates?

Example:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `date_ranges` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `content`, `date_ranges`) VALUES
  ('1', 'content1', '2018-10-30 - 2018-11-05/2018-11-12 - 2018-11-14/2019-01-15 - 2019-08-22'),
  ('2', 'content2', '2018-12-15 - 2018-12-17/2018-11-15 - 2018-11-22'),
  ('3', 'content3', '2018-09-30 - 2018-11-19/2018-11-11 - 2018-11-16/2019-01-16 - 2019-08-18/2018-10-30 - 2018-11-05'),
  ('4', 'content4', '2018-10-30 - 2018-11-05'),
  ('5', 'content5', '');
```

sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b2dcf/1

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. What RDBMS are you using specifically ?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Normalize your data please.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It is almost certainly MySQL (see the backticks).

Comment: "Normalize your data please." - It's necessary to do without changing the structure of the table, is this possible?

Comment: If you cannot change your application code and existing table structure, then you can create another table with normalized structure, and use triggers on the existing table to update the new table. Now, you can use a much simpler and performant query on the new table.

Comment: Query only solution would be quite tricky to make, and will involve lot of string operations (thus inefficient). Still, you can look for ideas from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120570/2469308